# S-Box used in AES 128 bit CFB mode of encryption

Tags: aes

Can anybody give me the S-Box used for 128 bit AES CFB mode of encryption.
Will this S-Box be same for every 128 -bit AES CFB Implementation.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_S-box) it is:

```
   | 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
---|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|
00 |63 7c 77 7b f2 6b 6f c5 30 01 67 2b fe d7 ab 76 
10 |ca 82 c9 7d fa 59 47 f0 ad d4 a2 af 9c a4 72 c0 
20 |b7 fd 93 26 36 3f f7 cc 34 a5 e5 f1 71 d8 31 15 
30 |04 c7 23 c3 18 96 05 9a 07 12 80 e2 eb 27 b2 75 
40 |09 83 2c 1a 1b 6e 5a a0 52 3b d6 b3 29 e3 2f 84 
50 |53 d1 00 ed 20 fc b1 5b 6a cb be 39 4a 4c 58 cf 
60 |d0 ef aa fb 43 4d 33 85 45 f9 02 7f 50 3c 9f a8 
70 |51 a3 40 8f 92 9d 38 f5 bc b6 da 21 10 ff f3 d2 
80 |cd 0c 13 ec 5f 97 44 17 c4 a7 7e 3d 64 5d 19 73 
90 |60 81 4f dc 22 2a 90 88 46 ee b8 14 de 5e 0b db 
a0 |e0 32 3a 0a 49 06 24 5c c2 d3 ac 62 91 95 e4 79 
b0 |e7 c8 37 6d 8d d5 4e a9 6c 56 f4 ea 65 7a ae 08 
c0 |ba 78 25 2e 1c a6 b4 c6 e8 dd 74 1f 4b bd 8b 8a 
d0 |70 3e b5 66 48 03 f6 0e 61 35 57 b9 86 c1 1d 9e 
e0 |e1 f8 98 11 69 d9 8e 94 9b 1e 87 e9 ce 55 28 df 
f0 |8c a1 89 0d bf e6 42 68 41 99 2d 0f b0 54 bb 16
```

It can also be found in [FIPS Pub 197](http://www.csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips197/fips-197.pdf), the official standard.

And yes, it is exactly the same for every implementation of AES. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to encrypt something others could decrypt or vice-versa.

Comment: actually i have seen this before, but my question is does every AES 128 bit encryption use the same S-box. 
In other words, if i am going to implement the 128 bit AES CFB mode algorithm and i use one particular s-box

Now assume you are also going to implement the same 128 bit AES CFB encryption will you also be using the same s-box?
DOes it make a difference if you use another one?
is there a standard s-box for different types of encryption.
I could not find any links which gave clear answers for these!